# ASP.NET 4.5 membership does not recognize SQL Server data provider at design time?

Tags: asp.net, sql, sql-server-2008-r2, membership-provider

I am new to Visual Studio 2012 / ASP.NET 4.5 web forms.

I am attempting to use forms authentication (`ASP.NET` membership) in my `asp.net 4.5 web forms` application (using `Visual Studio 2012`) as I have done successfully many times with `asp.net version 4.0`.

The problem seems to be that, when I am testing in `Visual Studio 2012`, it does not recognize my `web.config` settings pointing to an `SQL Server 2008R2 aspnetdb`.  It seems to be using the `SQL Express aspnetdb.mdf` file to store my users.

I have tried removing the `aspnetdb.mdf` completely from my web app and it still does not recognize my `web.config` settings pointing to the `SQL Server` and instead it uses the settings from somewhere else (don't know where!).  I know this because the `Membership.CreateUser()` method is throwing an error if I do not provide the question and answer as parameters.  Also the web configuration tool requires a question and answer to create a new user.  My `web.config` settings specifically do not!

When I host the web application, it DOES look for my users in the `SQL Server` database because when I try logging in with a user name that was successfully created using the web configuration tool in VS2012, my application cannot find that user!  It seems to be looking in `SQL Server` but cannot find it.

I must be missing some fundamental setting... Anyone have any thoughts?

I have included my web.config settings below:

```
<connectionStrings>    

  <add name="ApplicationServices" connectionString="Data Source=localhost;Initial Catalog=aspnetdb;Persist Security Info=True;User ID=studentid;Password=password" providerName="System.Data.SqlClient"/>
  <add name="StudentAttendanceConnectionString" connectionString="Data Source=localhost;Initial Catalog=StudentAttendance;Persist Security Info=True;User ID=studentid;Password=password" providerName="System.Data.SqlClient"/>
</connectionStrings>

<authentication mode="Forms">
<forms loginUrl="~/Account/Login.aspx" timeout="2880"/>      
</authentication>

<profile defaultProvider="DefaultProfileProvider">
  <providers>
    <add name="DefaultProfileProvider" type="System.Web.Providers.DefaultProfileProvider, System.Web.Providers, Version=1.0.0.0, Culture=neutral, PublicKeyToken=31bf3856ad364e35" connectionStringName="ApplicationServices" applicationName="/"/>
  </providers>
</profile>
<membership>
  <providers>
    <add connectionStringName="ApplicationServices" enablePasswordRetrieval="true"
      enablePasswordReset="false" requiresQuestionAndAnswer="false"
      requiresUniqueEmail="false" maxInvalidPasswordAttempts="5" minRequiredPasswordLength="6"
      minRequiredNonalphanumericCharacters="0" passwordAttemptWindow="10"
      applicationName="/" name="DefaultMembershipProvider" type="System.Web.Providers.DefaultMembershipProvider, System.Web.Providers, Version=1.0.0.0, Culture=neutral, PublicKeyToken=31bf3856ad364e35" />
  </providers>
 </membership>
 <roleManager>
  <providers>
    <add connectionStringName="ApplicationServices" applicationName="/"
      name="DefaultRoleProvider" type="System.Web.Providers.DefaultRoleProvider, System.Web.Providers, Version=1.0.0.0, Culture=neutral, PublicKeyToken=31bf3856ad364e35" />
  </providers>
  </roleManager>
```

Answer (score 0):

A few things...

1) Do the users or some account have access to the SQL database? I don't see that noted here.
2) Use the server name of the SQL server that appears when you fire up the SQL Management Studio and not localhost if IIS and SQL are on the same server.
3) Check your machine.config file for the version of .Net you're using.  I ended up having to change the SQL Express settings to the IP address of the server to get things working for me in a similar scenario along with removing (through the control panel) SQL Express or whatever test database VS 2012 installs.  I had errors related to this when building a server recently.

::edit::

Also add the following to your Web.Config file above the 'connectionStrings' section:

```
    <startup>
    <supportedRuntime version="4.0" sku=".NETFramework,Version=v4.5" />
    </startup>
```

Comment: Thank you for the answer!  Unfortunately it did not solve my problem.  I ended up creating a new web application in VS2012 but this time I deleted the App_Data/ aspnetdb.mdf file immediately then went into the web configuration tool and added a user.  This time it seemed to connect to my SQL Server ASPNETDB and add the user there.  However, I noticed that if I clicked on the Provider tab of the web configuration tool and selected the default provider, the problem started all over again!  I am analyzing my two web.config files to try to determine what the difference is...

Answer (score 0):

Could you try to create role and user using ASP.Net Config?

**VS2010**

[image]

Or

**VS 2012** > PROJECT > ASP.Net Configuration

Another one is to add clear - [Don't forget to  when adding providers](http://weblogs.asp.net/scottgu/archive/2006/11/20/common-gotcha-don-t-forget-to-clear-when-adding-providers.aspx)